# [React Select]: Move the 'create-option' to the top

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is it possible to have the 'create a new option' to be the first item in the list, such that if the user just type and press enter he searches on the query - and if the user sees some options in the dropdown, the user can press the arrow button down or select one from the list.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is:

```
createOptionPosition="first"
```

Thanks to ebonow at https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4276